# I have a problem with writing the content of ArrayLists into a file

Tags: java

So I wrote some code for a vocabulary trainer for my german class and want to write the content of my ArrayLists to a file. However it only writes the first of the 3 ArrayLists into the file when saving. Does anyone know what causes this, or better yet, how to fix it? Thanks for you help!

I have already reset all the ArrayLists and re-implemented the file it should write into, but nothing helped.

These are all just sequences of Code, not the whole program. It is over 400                                        lines Long so I didnt want to paste the whole thing. The Code runs flawlessly until I open the file I wrote into.

```
static ArrayList<String> vokabel = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> uebersetzung = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<Integer> kasten = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

static void beenden() {
  for(int m = 0; m < groesse; m++) {
    String str = vokabel.get(m).toString();
    textWriter.write(str);
    textWriter.write(" ");
  }
  textWriter.close();
  textWriter.println();
  for(int n = 0; n < groesse; n++) {
    String str = uebersetzung.get(n).toString();
    textWriter.write(str);
    textWriter.write(" ");
  }
  textWriter.close();
  textWriter.println();
  for(int o = 0; o < groesse; o++) {
    String str = kasten.get(o).toString();
    textWriter.write(str);
    textWriter.write(" ");
  }
  textWriter.close();
  textWriter.println();

  System.exit(0);

}
```

I expect it to write the content of all 3 ArrayLists into the file, though it didn't work up until now.
This is what ends up in the file after entering 3 words with their translations and their corresponding case number. Only the words themselves make it into the file:

Hund Nein Hallo

Comment: Don't close your writer in the middle of the code. Close it at the end of code.

Comment: I consider "calling close() in the middle of writing" as a typo-like error, thus voting to close

Comment: Beyond that: you are writing way to complicated code. There is **no** need to use a for-loop with an int counter: Simply do `for (String  lineToWrite : vokabel)` for example. That extra call to toString() is also nonsensical: the list contains strings, calling toString on String objects doesnt do anything useful.

Comment: Finally: A) use the list interface where possible and B) use the diamond operator and C) most importantly: use meaningful variable names, like `List<String> uebersetzungen = new ArrayList<>();` ... the variable name should express **plural**!

Comment: Final finally: dont use **multiple** list of Strings, that only "correlate" when using the same index value. Instead: define a class `Vokabel`. And a Vokabel contains a field `originalText` and another field `translatedText`. And then you have **one** list of objects of that class. And you can have a nice toString() methods that prints them together. And of course: typically, one English word can have multiple German words. And more interestingly: it can have several English synonyms. Consider to design your Vokabel class to reflect that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write all 3 lists one after the other. AND: Inbetween you close the writer! So you are "lucky" not to get an IOException.

I guess you would like the entries of the 3 lists together (vokabel + uebersetzung+ kasten). Therefore I suggest you create a class taking 3 fields with the information. Give this class a sensible toString() and simply write those objects one line at a time.

Ah and btw: Don't ever call System.exit! It makes your program unusable in a larger context and prevents proper cleanup of resources.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only writes the first `ArrayList` into the file is because you're closing the `TextWriter` immediately after writing it (and when the `TextWriter` is closed, it doesn't write stuff). Just remove all the

```
textWriter.close();
```

lines, and then put just one *right* before `System.exit(0)`, and it should work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Use Flush.when you have text longer than buffer size it will not write.

```
System.IO.TextWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("c:\\textwriter.txt");
writeFile.WriteLine("csharp.net-informations.com");
writeFile.Flush();
writeFile.Close();
```